# Are there any standalone Eclipse plugins for Ruby like PyDev for Python?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I can install PyDev for Eclipse and have pretty good Python IDE without any vendor preconfigurations. But surprisingly, I can't find a similar standalone IDE plugin for Ruby! Same company that supports PyDev, Aptana, offers something called "RadRails", but I could not find a way to install it separately - only as "Aptana Studio 3 Addin Plugin", and this "studio" includes not only Ruby - but also PyDev, PHP and lots of preconfigurations focused on web development.

What am I missing? Why can I install PyDev and have debugger/completion for python but for Ruby this leads for Eclipse bloated with "web perspectives", "web frameworks integration", etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two Ruby plugins for Eclipse. DLTK (the official Eclipse toolkit for dynamic languages) does support Ruby, and there is the RDT project.

There are also full-blown IDEs built on top of each: 3rd Rail by whatever-Borland-is-called-nowadays is built on top of DLTK/Ruby and RadRails by Apatana is built on top of RDT.

Comment: Thanks, i have checked DLTK - it's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [RDT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-rubyeclipse/)

Comment: actually, this was a predecessor of aptana - as it says at the bottom of the page ...

Comment: It seems that RDT was acquired by Aptana long time ago.

Comment: Actually, the guys who did RDT stopped working on it. Aptana hired the guy who did RadRails, and he also took over maintenance of RDT.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana is the only one I know of - though it doesn't really qualify as 'standalone' I suppose
[aptana studio](http://aptana.com/)

Comment: It's the problem i address in my question - Aptana is VERY bloated with Eclipse preconfiguration. And Eclipse is not very stable itself, so bloated version is much harder to configure and use.

Comment: Sorry - should read these questions to the end .... I've not tried to use aptana for a long time now, for the reasons you give